# Screen resolution suddenly decreased Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, resolution

My screen resolution suddenly decreased. I use (legal) win 10 for 3 years, reinstalled about half years ago. Last week my screen suddenly turned to black and then it came back with a lower resolution. Since then I cannot fix it, tried a lot of things.

1. Desktop Resolution

Obviously first I've checked the Resolution in the desktop's properties. *(The highest one is 1600x1200 and I've set that for comfort but it's scretched)*.

2. Default properties

Then I checked the default properties where I saw (and I don't know if it was different before the problem but I guess) Processor, DAC, Adapter, BIOS details are unknown (Grafics mem/Shared mem: 3967MB,Dedicated/System videomemory: 0MB) in the modes I can't change for a higher resolution because the monitor goes off if I set any higher. The monitor type: Generic PnP Monitor and Microsoft Basic Display Driver.

3. Update drivers

Then I've tried to update the adapter (auto detect says it's up to date, I don't know what does adapter mean so I cannot download a driver for it but I've downloaded "driver talent" that couldn't install a ATI Radeon 4000 HD because device was not recognized). Then I've tried to update monitor (up to date, and if I download the most recent driver it is not change anything, ASUS VW223D monitor type).

4. Uninstall, disable

In device manager I've tried to disable monitor to force re-recognition but it didn't work. Then I've uninstalled and restarted the computer. It didn't work as well. Then I used Display Driver Uninstaller, PC showed blue screen death then restarted. It couldn't boot so I pulled off everything then back, turned off power took out little battery and the memory cards then back. Then after a couple restart it could boot. Problem was the same but I've waited because I thought it is because of the uninstall, and after 1 hour it worked. Changed the screen to the proper resolution. It took for 10 or 15 minute, then it turned back to the low resolution.

5. What's next?

Some info: I have integrated video card, so the graphic specific stuff has always ran slow but it is acceptable for me. I use HDMI sometimes (but now it's not connected, and there's no other screen) I've checked cables, and screen with laptop (by the way it a desktop pc) and other monitor, everything worked well. Windows didn't update (I mean shortly) before the problem. CPU: AMD Athlon II X3 425

So **I need solution**, I don't want to reinstall windows (my experience it's not permanently problem will come back after a little time) or replace anything in PC. Is there any tips that I could try out?

EDIT:

I found some kind of solution with the GPU overclocking (on GPU with ATI Radeon driver) They suggest to raise the voltage or decrease the CPU clock. I don't want to try it before I'm not sure that It can't make any harm. Is there anybody who had used this solution for some problem?

PS: Sorry for my grammer mistakes!

Comment: "drawn" probably means "stretched" since you probably have a 720p or 1080p style monitor, and 1600x1200 is 4:3 aspect ratio (the wrong aspect ratio). "Integrated video card" is not helpful. Are you using the on-CPU GPU? Is it Intel? Is it AMD? Updating the video driver in device manager will only try to update the installed driver. The "Basic Microsoft" driver you list is the wrong driver, so you need to know what your proper device is. Ignore the monitor: the problem is your display device (GPU/grapchi card) is not recognized properly.

Comment: Yeah scretched sorry. So AMD Athlon II X3 425 and I guess on-CPU GPU (I'm not really into the hardwers so I'm not sure but I just don't have a graphic card) Where can I find the name of the display device?

Comment: You might try to rollback your drivers.  It soulds like Win Update installed "new drivers" that don't work for you.  Rolling back might be too late for what with all you've already done, but it *might* be possible.  Otherwise, you'll have to find the right drivers again, like @Yorik mentioned.  Get them from the manufacturers website, not through Win Updates.

Comment: I would, but I don't know that should I searching for. As @Yorik wrote I should download the display device's driver but I don't know where is the name of it or how can I get it, which hardwer should I looking for?

Comment: That CPU does not have on-die graphics, so the graphics are either on the motherboard or there's a riser card installed.

Comment: You are looking for the ATI Radeon 4000 drivers, and make sure the driver's compatibility list includes your exact video card.  If that doesn't work, then try the drivers for your ASUS VW223D again.  This link shows how to rollback the driver, if you haven't tried that yet: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-roll-back-a-driver-in-windows-2619217

Comment: Unfortunately none of them worked for me. But thanks for the tips! I have the latest motherboard driver and there's no riser card, and there's no previous version that I could rollback to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think overclocking your GPU will solve this, but you can try, what's the harm? OK, you could fry your GPU, but that's a one-in-a-million chance, you ask me.

Seriously, though, this is a driver issue: your screen has a certain definition, a fixed number of pixels, both vertically and horizontally, and obviously, Windows is using a driver that can accomodate that native resolution, for some reason.

You should download Snappy Driver from their website (https://sdi-tool.org/), decompress it, and run the SDI_1909 (if you have the latest, current version of Windows 10 to date) or SDI_x64_1909 application if you are running a 64-bit Windows 10.

When offered to download either a whole pack of drivers (all 60+GB worth) or just indexes, choose indexes, and in the left pane of the application, check boxes for "Better" drivers ("Not installed" and "More recent/newer" should already be checked).

Locate the graphics driver update in the list in the right pane, check the box next to it, or expand it and check one of the boxes underneath, then click on the green button in the top right corner labelled "Install".

And go grab a cup of tea or coffee, because it could take a while. You may have to reboot your PC afterwards, but that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows installs the drivers `Generic PnP Monitor` and `Microsoft Basic Display Driver` on a computer if your monitor and graphics card are unrecognizable or if there are no drivers available for them.
Why? Because, without these, you will be unable to see anything on your monitor screen.

**Note**: If your GPU was put inside your machine at the same time as your CPU, then it is likely to be very old. Such models have limited or no support. Finding the appropriate drivers will be difficult in such a scenario.

## What you can do:

1. Download [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html). If you
   are not sure about which file to download, use
   [this](https://download.cpuid.com/cpu-z/cpu-z_1.96-en.exe).
2. Open the Graphics tab. You will see something like [image: this].
3. Note down all names from the drop down list. These are the names of the GPUs/Graphics cards present inside your computer.
4. Go to your manufacturer's website and download the driver from there. Popular manufacturers: [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support) and [NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).